# Combinatorics: Number of ways to make 1500 dollars

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have 50 bills of 20\$ and 20 bills of 50\$ and 10 bills of 100\$. With how many ways a bank machine could make the 1500\$ ?

what I think is :as the cofficient of $x^{1500}$
in  $(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{1000})^3$

Comment: Hint: Any valid combination of bills has an even number of 50\$ bills and the number of 20\$ bills will be a multiple of 5.

Comment: Your generating function is wrong. Why would you have terms $x^0, x^1, \ldots x^{1000}$? The available bills are only 20, 50 and 100 so certainly you would only have $x^{20}, x^{50}$ and $x^{1000}$ in this kind of expression. And why something to the power of three?

Comment: so it's wrong thanks a lot Matti

Comment: Note how the different sections of the generating function actually represent the problem... the first parenthetical phrase representing the answer to the question "*how many 20\$ bills were used*" etc... and that we ended at  $x^{1000}$ because it corresponds to the largest amount you could make with $50$ 20\$ bills, and similar for the other sections.

Comment: You could use generating functions if you so choose.  I don't recommend it as it isn't necessary here, that's more often a last-effort if other methods fail.  It would look instead like $(1+x^{20}+x^{40}+x^{60}+\dots+x^{1000})(1+x^{50}+x^{100}+x^{150}+\dots+x^{1000})(1+x^{100}+x^{200}+x^{300}+\dots+x^{1000})$

Comment: Never mind how many bills you have, how many does the bank machine have? :-)

Comment: $$(x20+x40+x60+⋯)(x50+x100+x150+⋯)(x100+x200+x^300+⋯)$$ this is wrong? @JMoravitz

Comment: Yes, what you just wrote in your comment is wrong for a few reasons.  First, you need to fix your styling.  `x^{300}` is how you write an exponent.   As to the content, you forgot to include $x^0$, or better written as $1$ at the front of each of those.  Next, you forgot to write a final term in each of $x^{1000}$.  Ellipses without a final term imply it would go on indefinitely but that is not the case here.  We can not go on indefinitely because we are limited in the number of each bill available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that you can't have a lone \$50 bill - they must always be paired with another to make a multiple of \$100. Then the same applies to \$20 bills, except they need to appear in packs of $5$, again to make a \$100 bundle.

This simplifies the issue considerably, since now you have 3 stacks of $10$ items: \$100 bills, \$50 pairs, \$20 bundles, with each item worth \$100.

So now it's a division with limits. We can enumerate picking $15$ items from $3$ classes with $\binom {15+2}2$. Then we can remove all cases when we pick more of than one class than the $10$ allowed by allocating $11$ items to each class in turn and counting how we can divide the remaining $4$ items.

So the result is $\binom {17}{2}-3\binom {6}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

To keep numbers small let's divide the note values by $10$ so we have $50$ of $2$, $20$ of $5$ and $10$ of $10$ and want to make $150$. Because the other two denominations and the target amount are divisible by $5$, in all ways of making $150$ the number of $2$ notes must be a multiple of $5$, so effectively we have $10$ notes of $10$ but in a different kind – think different series of notes. Then, by the same logic, the number of $5$ notes used must be even, so it is like $10$ notes of $10$ in a third kind. Now we can divide note values by $10$ again, leading to the ultimate reduced question:

> What is the number of integer solutions to $a+b+c=15$ where $0\le a,b,c\le10$?

We count the number of ways with no upper limit on the variables, which is $\binom{15+3-1}{3-1}=136$, then subtract the number of ways where one of the variables is at least $10$: three times the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $a+b+c=4$, equalling $45$. Thus the final answer is $91$: there are $91$ ways for the ATM to dispense \$1500.